# Is "function" required in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there any way to tidy up this script?

```
$( ".switchViewHide" ).click(function() {
  $( ".topTitles h2" ).fadeOut( "slow", function(){});
  $(".topControls h3").fadeOut("slow"), function(){};
  $(".topControls h3").fadeOut("slow"), function(){};
  $("#videoControls p").fadeOut("slow"), function(){};
  $("#pageControls div.switchViewHide").fadeOut("slow"), function(){};
  $("#pageControls div.switchViewShow").fadeIn("slow"), function(){};
  $("#countdownBar").fadeOut("slow"), function(){};
  $("#grid").fadeOut("slow"), function(){};
});
```

I tried removing "function" as it's empty but it no longer works.

- Essentially on click of the button all those elements disappear (fade
  out).
- Plus one element fades in (it's a button replacement)
- And a CSS class will be adeed (using .addClass)

It looks a bit messy, is there an easier way to apply lots of different things on one click?

Comment: There's this thing: `$.noop`, but I wouldn't call this "tidying up".

Comment: there is no need for them, you are not even passing the function to the fadeOut method....

Comment: Is this you actual code? Some of those parenthesis are wrong.

Comment: it's an optional argument, signified by being wrapped in `[]` in the documentation. you can just leave it out.

Comment: The documentation says you should be able to remove function(){} without consequences. What do you mean by "it no longer works"? Could you provide a jsFiddle that illustrates your problem?

Comment: Change `$( ".topTitles h2" ).fadeOut( "slow", function(){});` to `$( ".topTitles h2" ).fadeOut("slow");`

Comment: looks at http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uwHF7/1/ - you are just dumping some `function(){}` here and there.... see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uwHF7/2/

Comment: Why do you have this twice? `$(".topControls h3").fadeOut("slow"), function(){};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can check, the function is optional

```
$( ".switchViewHide" ).click(function() {
    $( ".topTitles h2" ).fadeOut("slow");
    $(".topControls h3").fadeOut("slow");
    // $(".topControls h3").fadeOut("slow"); // duplicate
    $("#videoControls p").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#pageControls div.switchViewHide").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#pageControls div.switchViewShow").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#countdownBar").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#grid").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

---

You can do this A LOT simpler by using classes, or even toggle when you want them back:

```
$( ".switchViewHide" ).click(function() {
    // These will work once
    $(".HideOnClick").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".ShowOnClick").fadein("slow");
});

$( ".switchViewHide" ).click(function() {
    // These will toggle every click, based on their start visibility
    $(".toggleVisibility").stop().fadeToggle("slow");
    // Note the `.stop()`, when you click really fast a couple of times, it will queue animation
    // stop will stop the current animation, and continue to the next one.
});
```

---

The code can do a bit better. When you have an ID as start, combo that with `find()` for better performance ( jQuery uses the fast `getElementById()` of javascript itself):

```
// not so good
$("#pageControls div.switchViewShow")
// better:
$("#pageControls").find("div.switchViewShow")
```

In the first line, ALL `div.switchViewShow` will be looked up, in the **whole** document, then removing all those who are not in #pageControls.
In the second line all `div.switchViewShow` will be looked up, but only in the `#pageControls`

**A good read (also for more experienced programmers!):**
http://lprocksit.blogspot.nl/2012/05/jquery-advanced-performance-best.html
http://blog.sathomas.me/post/jquery-best-practices

Comment: Nothing wrong with: `$("#pageControls div.switchViewShow")`. The first article you linked states *"The $.fn.find approach is faster because the first selection is handled without going through the Sizzle selector engine"*. Yet sizzle will default to `querySelectorAll` when it can (which is almost always), and even if you separate the `div.switchViewShow`, it'll *still* need to go through Sizzle. If it was just `.switchViewShow`, jQuery *may* optimize with `getElementsByClassName`. Either way, it isn't going to add much more overhead to the already large overhead already present using jQuery.

Comment: Yes, but the id wont go through Sizzle, and the area the Sizzle-,ethod has to look through is (when properly done) significantly smaller. Im not a mega-jQuery-pro, but I've tested this a bit, and in large selections it's noticably faster

Comment: Small bonus in selecting the id first, is that you can save the pointer in a variable, and use it more often. But that depends on the case.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, `$('#id .class')` is SLOWER than `$('.class')` [JsPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-class-vs-tag-qualfied-class-selector/10). That isn't the only bogus advice in the articles.

Comment: They say you shouldn't do `$('#id .class')`, but `$('#id').find('.class')`. In my tests they are faster. Might differ from version to version, but I like speed, and I have a website I can test those on

Comment: Also, it explains why it is slower. If first selects all `.class` AND it verifies wether or not they're a child of `#id`. Sizzle goes right to left.

Comment: @Martijn whether the first or second is faster depends a lot on how your dom looks like. Class lookups are optimized natively and so are id lookups. id.find(class) has to pretty much iterate through the whole subtree whos root is id, which if small can be fast, but it can also be horribly big. Class lookups alone will always be fast.

Comment: In the example you gave, I asumed you **dont** want ALL classes, only those who decend from `#id`. If you want all of them, you should not use ID, I completely agree with you on that